# Why does this GCD example code seem to improperly release an object?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch

In [wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch#Examples) author has `release`d the object `stats`, when it has not been allocated, copied, or retained. Is this an error or something I don't understood?

```
- (IBAction)analyzeDocument:(NSButton *)sender
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    NSDictionary *stats = [myDoc analyze];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [myModel setDict:stats];
      [myStatsView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
      [stats release];
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is either an error or it is properly documented that `analyze` returns ownership of the object to the caller. If it is not an error that `stats` is released then that codes example is using a convention that goes against [Apple's memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) for ownership.

> Memory-management rules, sometimes referred to as the ownership
>   policy, help you to explicitly manage memory in Objective-C code.
>
> You own any object you create by allocating memory for it or copying
>   it. 
>   *Related methods: alloc, allocWithZone:, copy, copyWithZone:,
>   mutableCopy, mutableCopyWithZone:*

Another prefix that should return ownership is the class method `+new`. E.g. `[MyDocClass newAnalysis];`

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example [cooked up by John Siracusa](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2009/08/mac-os-x-10-6/13/) to demonstrate how GCD can easily put a long-running task into the background, but, yes, it has one of two problems, one an ingored convention, the other an actual error.

It's possible that the fictional `analyze` method returns an owning reference. This is a violation of Cocoa convention that methods not named `new`, `alloc`, `release`, or `copy...` generally *don't* return such references, but if the documentation made clear that it did, and there was really no way around it, it could be all right. In this case, sending `release` to `stats` would be necessary to avoid a memory leak. (If this were real code, renaming the method would be a good idea, perhaps using `create` which is used in CoreFoundation to signify return of an owning reference.)

If, however, `analyze` follows convention and returns a non-owned reference, then you're right, sending `release` to `stats` is incorrect and will eventually cause a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `analyze` is returning a dictionary with a retain count of 1 which is why the `release` is needed.